# Which LEGO figure is this with white cape and red suit with a lightning bolt?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

Could somebody please identify the minifigure in the picture please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Shazam, a superhero from DC,

[image: A picture of the minifigure]

Paint seems a bit faded in your case, but this is the one.

This is a very rare minifig because it's a Comic-Con 2012 exclusive.

ID sh042 in Bricklink

Comment: As posted in the other answer, you have a knock-off version of sh042. Not worth much, if anything at all. Print on yours is all wonky, misaligned and definitely not something that would have passed LEGO’s QA stage.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the Comic-Con 2012 exclusive Shazam / Captain Marvel: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sh042#T=I

From the quality of the lighting in the photo it's hard to be definitive but if I had to guess I'd say this isn't genuine Lego but a reproduction figure or knock-off (KO).

Comment: Thank you for your information. The lighting wasnt the greatest and picture was taken on older mobile phone , will try and poat a better quality photo now. Thanks again

Comment: Compared to the Bricklink photo, this opened mouth is skew. Also, the fabric of the cape is not LEGOlike at all. This is definitely not LEGO.